# reset my project .csproj file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-assembly, badimageformatexception

I'm working with c# in .net 4.0. my question is how to reset my project settings. like csproj files, reference files. why because is my project could not find some dll(references). while running with release mode it's working fine. but debug mode it's can't run properly. missing some dll file what we added in reference list. so is there any way to reset my project settings?any one please help me

Answer (score 3):

Resetting not obviously solve the problem. Try to open the csproj file in a notepad and inspect the reference section on which all references are listed. Once you have this,it is easy to nail down the reference related issues.

Comment: But in my project csproj file doesn't contain any reference dll's in reference section. so what happens to my project?

Comment: What you are exactly trying to on debug mode which is not part of release. Are you debugging any code which is not part of your actual source code ? If so can you make sure u have .pdb file in debug directory. If these are not the case, can you post the actual issue/debug message which you get while debugging.